# Array to String Conversion Error/Problems

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am a PHP newbie, and keep on getting "PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion" when I attempt this code given to me to loop through INSERTing items into a database.  I need to loop through, because I am using an ajax script to dynamically read form field data as you add/remove fields, and pushing it through the php as $idx allows $idx to be incremented, allowing my dynamic addition of INSERTS.

Does anyone know how to alter this to make it work, and PLEASE tell me how/why/what you did so I can learn for future uses.  THANKS!!

My PHP :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO items (WID, model, description, cost, retail, qty) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $idx = 0;
        foreach ($Model as $model_idx) {
            $q->execute(array($wid,$model_idx, $Description[$idx], $Cost[$idx], $Retail[$idx], $Quantity[$idx]));
            $idx++;
        }
```

My Php/Html :

```
<div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($ModelError)?'error':'';?>">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" data-type="model" name="model[]" id="model_1" placeholder="Model" value="<?php echo !empty($Model)?$Model:'';?>" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">
                                            <?php if (!empty($ModelError)): ?>
                                                <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $ModelError;?></span>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
```

Validation/String Output :

```
if ( !empty($_POST)) {
        // keep track validation $

        $ModelError       = null;
        $DescriptionError = null;
        $CostError        = null;
        $RetailError      = null;
        $QuantityError    = null;

        // keep track post values

        $Model        = $_POST['model'];
        $Description  = $_POST['description'];
        $Cost         = $_POST['cost'];
        $Retail       = $_POST['retail'];
        $Quantity     = $_POST['quantity'];

        // validate input
        $valid = true;
        if (empty($Model)) {
            $ModelError = 'Please enter Model';
            $valid = false;
        }
```

Comment: You should not be running queries in a loop.

Comment: @StuartWagner    It is not, the form fields are added via ajax as needed, and as soon as the user clicks on "Submit" the items are added into the database(or are supposed to be).  In that manner, you can have a form that adds 3 items to a database, or 30(think invoicing)

Comment: can you show what come in `$Model`?

Comment: Does `$Model` contains other arrays ?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh What do you mean?  Model is part of the table, which consists of Model, Description, Cost, Retail, etc - That div code is a sample of the whole, there is a div for each of the above.  The php cycles through each of the added ajax elements by the model, because the model is mandatory in my form fields.

Comment: @DavidDomain $Model could just as easily be $WID or $Description, the one value contains all of the information for this form field, which contains A model #, description, retail, and cost

Comment: `echo "<pre/>";print_r($Model);` use it and show what content it have?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh it just shows <pre/> and nothing else, took out the <pre/>; and it just shows "Model"

Comment: Are you sure that `$ModelError` is a string?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh That fixed the error, the items are still not adding to the database though....

Comment: @DavidDomain I have errors(such as $ModelError) translating to strings, such as "please select model", I added the code as an example

Comment: @anantkumarsingh The error is fixed which was my original question/not the fact my database is not being updated, which is another question.  If you post the reason you used print r in the loop, I will select it as best answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated the problem is `Array to String conversion` that means in your code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO items (WID, model, description, cost, retail, qty) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $idx = 0;
        foreach ($Model as $model_idx) {
            $q->execute(array($wid,$model_idx, $Description[$idx], $Cost[$idx], $Retail[$idx], $Quantity[$idx]));
            $idx++;
        }
```

Here `$Model` is not act as an array so try to print it out by `echo "<pre/>";print_r($Model);` or `var_dump($Model);` and check any array is coming or not?

If not then check your html code and try to resolve it.

Also i am not sure how's you are getting/making these variables `$wid,$model_idx, $Description[$idx], $Cost[$idx], $Retail[$idx], $Quantity[$idx]` .